# Need to incorporate if else statement within my code

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am trying to achieve if else statement or case statement within my code below.  I want to use one of these statement (if or case) to see if my RT_Ch_Pres_PX1 values are within certain min or max specs if they are above or below I want to say that if my RT_Ch_Pres_PX1 is below my min value by this much then display that value and indicate by how much is it of by and same this for exceeding max value.  for example if my RT_Ch_Pres_PX1 value is 5 and I want to use my min valuse at 6 and max at 10. So my Rt_Ch_pres_px1 value is off by 1 so I would like to display this and say this value is of by 1 value.  if RT_Ch_Pres_PX1 is within min and max values do nothing.   Please see code below.

```
                    DECLARE @Result TABLE
            (
                        RT_DateTime datetime,
                        RT_Phase_Name varchar(30),
                        RT_PhaseChangeCount int,
                        RT_Phase_Type int,
                        RT_Ch_Pres_PX1 float           
            );
            /* Variables used to track changes to Phase Name */
            DECLARE @RT_DateTime datetime;
            DECLARE @RT_Phase_Name varchar(30);
            DECLARE @RT_PhaseChangeCount int;
            DECLARE @RT_Phase_Type int;
            DECLARE @RT_Ch_Pres_PX1 float;
            DECLARE @PhaseNameHold varchar(30);
            DECLARE @PhaseChangeCount int;
            SELECT @PhaseNameHold = ' ';
            SELECT @PhaseChangeCount = 0;
            SELECT @RT_PhaseChangeCount = 0;

            /* Declare a cursor for determining when Phases change */

            DECLARE ImportCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR

            SELECT 
            CONVERT(datetime, dbo.CycleData.Date_Time) as TimeConvert, 
            [dbo].[LookupPhases].[Phase_Name],
            [dbo].[cycledata].[phase_type],
            [dbo].[cycledata].[Ch_Pres_PX1]

            FROM
             CycleData INNER JOIN
                                     CycleDataHeader ON CycleData.Unit_Number = CycleDataHeader.Unit_Number AND CycleData.Cycle_Counter_No = CycleDataHeader.Cycle_Counter_No INNER JOIN
                                     LookupPhases ON CycleData.Phase_Type = LookupPhases.Phase_Type INNER JOIN
                                     LookupEvent ON CycleData.Event_Type = LookupEvent.Event_Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                     LookupAlarm ON CycleData.Alarm_Type = LookupAlarm.Alarm_Id

              WHERE 
            [dbo].[CycleDataHeader].[Entered_Load_No1] = 'T14-0008'


            ORDER BY

            /* Appears to be the order that needs to be reported on */

            Cycle_Time
            -- dbo.CycleData.Unit_Number,

            -- TimeConvert;

            OPEN ImportCursor;

            FETCH NEXT FROM ImportCursor INTO @RT_DateTime, 
                                                @RT_Phase_Name,
                                                @RT_Phase_Type,
                                                @RT_Ch_Pres_PX1  
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
            IF (@RT_Phase_Name <> @PhaseNameHold)   
                BEGIN
                                    SET @PhaseNameHold = @RT_Phase_Name;
                                    SET @RT_PhaseChangeCount = @RT_PhaseChangeCount + 1;
                                    END
                        INSERT INTO @Result VALUES(@RT_DateTime, @RT_Phase_Name,@RT_PhaseChangeCount,@RT_Phase_Type,@RT_Ch_Pres_PX1);           
                        FETCH NEXT FROM ImportCursor INTO @RT_DateTime, @RT_Phase_Name,@RT_Phase_Type,@RT_Ch_Pres_PX1;
            END
            CLOSE ImportCursor;
            DEALLOCATE ImportCursor;
            SELECT
                        RT_DateTime,
                        RT_Phase_Name,
                        RT_PhaseChangeCount,
                        RT_Phase_Type,
                        RT_Ch_Pres_PX1 


            FROM @Result;
```

Comment: What about your current code isn't working?  Does it return an error?

Answer (score 0):

This case will generate the value you want:

```
case
  when RT_Ch_Pres_PX1 < some_min then RT_Ch_Pres_PX1 - some_min
  when RT_Ch_Pres_PX1 > some_max then RT_Ch_Pres_PX1 - some_max
  else 0
end
```

The value created for the undershoot is negative (a good idea I think). If you want it to be positive, flip the calculation.

Comment: Thank for replying.  The main question is that where can I incorporate this case statement in my code.  This is the part I am having difficulty with.

Comment: @Eric Hauenstein -  My code is working fine but I need to have a min and a max which would tell me if my RT_Ch_Pres_PX1 values is within my specs for everytime my phases changes

Comment: How can I use the case statement for different RT_Phase_Name and setting the RT_Phase_Name with my RT_Ch_Pres_PX1 to see for that RT_Phase_Name phase is within my RT_Ch_Pres_PX1

Comment: You can either assign this to a variable or include it a select statement which is read into a variable. It's hard to answer with working code when you didn't provide the variable names that contain you min/max values.

Comment: the min/max values will we hard coded (manually typed into my code for each phases based on my phasechangecount)